# How to add one long scrollable image into HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

(Beginner question)
Hello, I'm trying to create a site that has one long image as a background that you can scroll. Nothing fancy, just one image of 1920x3740 of which you can only see a viewport-sized section of. I added an image to clarify what I mean.
[image: one big iamge with the viewport scrolling through it]

I've tried using multiple divs under each other of 1920x1080, and chopped the image up to fit correctly, which kind of worked, but they wouldn't stay 16x9 so the edges of each image didn't match up. Now what i've got is one big image but I can't scroll it.

HTML:

```
<div class="bgImageFull"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.bgImageFull{
  background-image: url(../images/LandingPage/NEW_TAHIN_IMAGE_FULL.jpg);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This also goes before but I don't think it does anything for my issue:

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html, body{
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'functionPro';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.bgImageFull {
    background-image: url(../images/LandingPage/NEW_TAHIN_IMAGE_FULL.jpg);
    height: 3740px;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Height: 100%; Could be what's messing this up for you.

It might be better to specify the actual height of your image in the image's class. 100% is just going to cover the available height of the parent element.

Comment: Wow, how come I didn't think of this yet?! TYSM! It scales from 1080p width to infinity, but the only problem is that it won't go lower while displaying the full width of the image. Which in this case actually isn't too bad, but do you know how I would do that?

Comment: Edit to first comment: Hmm upon further inspection, it works well enough for normal screens, but when I scale the window up, the bottom of the image is cut off because the height is fixed. The full image should always remain visible. Weirdly I can't find much about this problem on the internet...

Comment: I could also be misunderstanding what you're attempting to do. It seems like you're trying to create a responsive layout of some kind. Do you have any screenshots for reference?

Comment: Adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) might help too

Comment: Sorry! I just fixed it. I used a height of 200vw, so the height would be relative to the current viewport width. But thanks for the insights, im a complete beginner on stack overflow so what you've just suggested will definitely help.in the future. Thanks again!